# Watching an iPad live stream on PC using VLC

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, url, video-streaming, ipad

I found a video streaming app on the App Store that lets you watch live streams of certain channels on your iPad, but because the iPad screen's quite small and the app doesn't support AirPlay mirroring I wanted to find a way to watch the streams on my desktop computer.

I packet sniffed the stream URL the app was using but when I tried to open it using VLC, I get this error:

> Your input can't be opened: VLC is unable to open the MRL. Check the log for details.

[Here's a screenshot of the stream URLs in case it helps.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zir7.png) As the list shows, each URL contains a timestamp at the end that's updated regularly. A new stream URL (ending in .ts) and an accompanying .m3u8 file is generated whenever the timestamp changes. I've tried opening several different URL's without success.

If anyone could help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance -
David